# Rails & Poltergeist: Screen won't resize for screenshots

Tags: ruby-on-rails, poltergeist

I'm trying to take a screenshot using Poltergeist, and its getting a picture, but now I want to change the screen size of the screenshot.

Here's what I have so far:

```
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
require 'spec_helper'
include Warden::Test::Helpers

describe 'PhantomJS' do
  before do
    page.driver.resize_window(1920, 1080)
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    login_as(@user, :scope => :user)
  end

  it "should take a screenshot", :js => true do
    visit root_path

    page.save_screenshot('lib/screenshot.png')
  end
end
```

However this is returning an image that is 1000x1437. The resize doesn't seem to do anything for the screenshot. Does anyone know why the resize isn't affecting it/how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: isn't the resize method resize and not resize_window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try setting :full option

```
page.save_screenshot('lib/screenshot.png', :full => true)
```

Check if your content resizes on window resize.